# Projection on the GNS subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, projection

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $C^{*}$-algebra.
If $\omega$ is a positive linear functional on $\mathcal{A}$, then we may perform the so-called GNS construction in order to obtain ha Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{\omega}$, a representation $\pi_{\omega}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_{\omega})$, and a cyclic vector $\xi_{\omega}\in\mathcal{H}_{\omega}$ for $\pi_{\omega}$ such that
$$
\omega(a)=\langle\xi_{\omega}|\pi_{\omega}(a)\xi_{\omega}\rangle .
$$

We may always decompose $\mathcal{H}_{\omega}$ as the direct sum of the closed subspace $H_{\xi_{\omega}}$  generated by $\xi_{\omega}$ and its orthogonal complemetn $H_{\xi_{\omega}}^{\perp}$. 
Let me call $H_{\xi_{\omega}}$ the GNS subspace of $\omega$.

Clearly, the orthogonal projection $P$ onto the GNS subspace of $\omega$ is an element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_{\omega})$, and I would like to know if there exists a projection $e\in\mathcal{A}$ (depending on $\omega$, of course) such that 
$$
\pi_{\omega}=P
$$
If it helps, $\mathcal{A}$ may be taken to be a von Neumann algebra, and $\omega$ to be normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection $e$ cannot exist for $\omega$ faithful when $\mathcal A$ is simple and $\mathcal A\ne\mathbb C$. For instance, it will never exist for a II$_1$-factor, even if $\omega$ is normal. For C$^*$-algebras, you have the added problem that $\mathcal A$ may lack projections.

Write $\hat a$ for the class of $a\in \mathcal A$ in $\mathcal H_\omega$. You have that (recall that $\xi_\omega=\hat 1$)
$$\tag1
P\hat a=\langle \hat a,\xi_\omega\rangle\,\xi_\omega=\langle \hat a,\hat 1\rangle\,\hat 1=\omega(a)\,\hat 1.
$$
Now you want $P=\pi(e)$ for some projection $e\in \mathcal A$. Then the above becomes 
$$\tag2
\pi(e)\hat a=\omega(a)\,\hat 1,
$$
which is
$$\tag3
\widehat {ea}=\omega(a)\,\hat 1.
$$
Because  $\omega$ is faithful, $ea=\omega(a)1$ for all $a\in A$. This requires $\dim \mathcal A=1$.

Comment: Why does the state need to be faithful? It seems the question is about general states.

Comment: Not sure where you are going with that.

Comment: I'm wondering about a similar question. What kind of elements in A gets mapped to a projection by the GNS construction. We may assume the state is pure. Are there nice enough characterizations?

Comment: About the previous reply: basically why assume a state is faithful.

Comment: Because the question asked about a general property, and I gave a counterexample: actually many, because any faithful functional on any simple C$^*$-algebra would give one.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I was too interested in the answer to this question for pure states, that blinded me to the actual question raised. Maybe this problem would interest you:) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800229/projections-on-the-gns-hilbert-space-of-a-pure-state